# SOLR Failed Full Import

Tags: java, solr

During Indexing, I get the below error in Solr Logging screen:

Please help me: how to trouble shoot this error and if possible, a solution to resolve the error.

Not sure whether the error is caused due to something in the schema.xml or solrconfig.xml files.

data config XML file is connected to SQL server database and sqljdbc42 JAR.

I have disabled JMX and Velocity Response Writer as a recent change.

```
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Error invoking script for entity stackoverflow Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:270)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:185)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2064)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:654)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:450)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Error invoking script for entity stackoverflow Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Error invoking script for entity stackoverflow Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:70)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ScriptTransformer.transformRow(ScriptTransformer.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.applyTransformer(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:198)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:256)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/zzz": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:397)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:199)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:386)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ScriptTransformer.transformRow(ScriptTransformer.java:55)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/zzz": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$7$14$\^eval\_.poc(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 49 more
```

Data Config:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jf3mNilm6QYuQNwsrvGX1c_6rnv0Yrmb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like you’re trying to execute */tmp/zzz* but it doesn’t exist.  Maybe posting your data config xml file would help.

Comment: Hi @MarkSholund,

Thank you for responding. I have uploaded the data config file to drive. Please find the file in the link.

Comment: `/tmp/zzz` sounds like a typical executable location from a rootkit or something similar that have gained access, or attempted to gain access through parts of the configuration, to your Solr server. Is your Solr server exposed directly to the world?

Comment: I don’t see anything in your config that points to this error. I too wonder if you have a root kit.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh

Thank you for responding. Yes, the solr instance has access from the internet. How do I move forward from here?

Comment: HI @MarkSholund

Thank you very much for verifying the data config.

Comment: You nuke the server, reinstall it, set up a new Solr instance that isn't exposed to the internet, and reindex your content from your source.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh

Thank you for suggestion. I will go ahead and stop the server and reinstall another server and reinstall Solr.